# findall and xpath problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

I have a text file contains some HTML code called "html.txt" as shown as below:

```
<tr>
    <td class="name"><a href="/player/DAVID:RD" class=""><span>David Kwan</span> (DAVID)</a></td>
    <td class="teamid" style="">DAVID:RD</td>
    <td class="">District Player</td>
    <td class="">Red-Dragon Factory</td>
</tr>
```

Referring to the tutorial I read from the lxml website, I tried to use the `etree` and `findall()` methods to extract the table data from the HTML code, but somehow I'm not able to print out in string format, the result I get is `<Element td at 0x267c1c0>`.
I understand a set or list will return similar when using the `findall` method, but even if I use the index 0 it also does not help. Also, using trial and error I attempted to use the `str` function that support the `xpath` to force `findall` return in string format also does not help.

Can someone advise me on how to correct this?

```
from lxml import etree

page = open("C:/Python27/project/lxml_project/html.txt").read()
x = etree.HTML(page)
element = (x.findall('.//td[@class="teamid"]'))
print(element)
```

My second question is if I use the `xpath` instead of `findall` method, will it be a better solution? Previously when I tried xpath, it always returned me the first search element even I have multiples of table data `<td>` tags in the entire html page. Is it possible to implement `xpath` recursively with the use of Python LXML library?

Comment: And what output did you expect? You found an element, but what data did you want to extract from the element?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response...
In fact, i want to print out the value of the "teamid" which is DAVID:RD

when using xpath i think i can do something like that:
element = (x.findall('string(.//td[@class="teamid"])'))

I only add the string to print out DAVID:RD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Element.text` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) to retrieve the text content of an element:

```
elements = x.findall('.//td[@class="teamid"]')
print([elem.text for elem in elements])
```

`.findall()` returns a list; you can use `.find()` to retrieve just the first match (or `None` if there are no matching elements).

Comment: Thanks and appreciate it.
Is it i still need to do conversion in order to print out direct DAVID:RD instead of ['DAVID:RD']?

Comment: @user3622414: use `elements[0].text` or `x.find()` if you just need the one match.

Comment: Cool. It works very well and i think elements[0].text is more suit want i wanna do because eventually i will use the code in the long html page. Thanks again.

Comment: May i know if i should use "findall" or "xpath" to perform this kind of extraction? If i wanna let the script perform faster extraction (I have many html pages and many data row + data) , which one i should choose? Please advice...

Comment: See http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#what-are-the-findall-and-xpath-methods-on-element-tree, there is no speed advantage to using one or the other, just expressiveness vs. compatibility with the original ElementTree API.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters, the explanation is great. :)